# Is observable and promise compatible in rxjs?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

In the official [angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) it contains the following code

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);

  console.log(this.route.params);
  console.log(this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])));
}
```

Now we know that `this.route.params` returns an observable, while 
 `this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])` returns a promise

Here is the signature for `rxjs` `switchmap`

```
switchMap(project: function: Observable, resultSelector: function(outerValue, innerValue, outerIndex, innerIndex): any): Observable
```

We see that the first parameter takes a function that emits an observable.

However in the example above we actually passed in a function that emits a promise.

Are they compatible with each other?

Furthermore the console

```
console.log(this.route.params
.switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])));
```

outputs

```
AnonymousSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array[0], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false…}
```

shouldnt the `_isScalar` be set to true, since the function outputs a promise?

Comment: You might be looking for `Observable#fromPromise` ([v4 docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/v4.1.0/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md), [v5 docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise))

Comment: @Whymarrh so is `fromPromise` implicitly called in the example I provided above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many places, the RxJS API accepts an [`ObservableInput`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.3/src/Observable.ts#L18):

```ts
export type ObservableInput<T> = SubscribableOrPromise<T> | ArrayLike<T>;
```

Which can be an observable, a promise or an array-like, iterable object.

In the code you have included in your question, the `project` function passed to [`switchMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.0.3/src/operator/switchMap.ts#L10) returns a promise. That's fine, as `switchMap` accepts `project` functions that return an `ObservableInput`:

```ts
export function switchMap<T, R>(
  this: Observable<T>,
  project: (value: T, index: number) => ObservableInput<R>
): Observable<R>;
```

The `switchMap` implementation will see that the promise is converted to an observable.

Regarding the resultant observable's *internal* `_isScalar` property, it will be set to `true` when the promise resolves and the resolved value is stored within the observable. My understanding is that in RxJS, *scalar* does not refer the the number of values that will be emitted, but instead refers to whether or not said values are available for immediate emission.